# How to make a textview appear and disappear?

Tags: java, android, xml

The default is disappear.  I want to know how to make a `text-view` appear and disappear.

Comment: do you know the concept of thread.

Comment: no what is a thread?

Comment: use AlphaAnimation.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set particular `View's` visibility Like :

```
yourTextViewName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) // For Visible/Appear

yourTextViewName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)  // For Invisible/Disappear

yourTextViewName.setVisibility(View.GONE)   // For Gone / View not takes any space at Run time
```

Hope this will Helps.(:

Comment: Thanks, is there a method for making it appear after you make it gone?

Comment: Use yourTextViewName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) for Visible Even after GONE

Answer (score 2):

Here is the method you are looking for;

```
private void makeTextViewDisappear(){
    yourTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            yourTV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // OR yourTV.setVisibility(View.GONE) to reclaim the space used by textview
        }
    }, 10000); //for 10 seconds
}
```

If this worked, don't forget to mark this as the right answer. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   yourTextViewName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                }
            }, 5000); <--- change time here
```

Comment: It is better to include some context/explanation for code as that makes the answer more useful to the OP and to future readers.